# REVTEX: Increase spacing above references

Tags: revtex

I am using REVTEX to typeset a document. Now, I would like to change the spacing above and below that horizontal line that separates the text and the references. I was trying to find where this is set, but couldn't. Does anyone know how to do this?

A minimal example is as follows:

```
\documentclass[reprint]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\begin{thebibliography}{1}
\bibitem {}Reference 1
\bibitem {}Reference 2
\bibitem {}Reference 3
\bibitem {}Reference 4
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

Note that just including additional lines by line breaks or \vspace will not do due to the two-column formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spacing is done in a macro `\bibsection` defined in the file `aps4-1.rtx`, which is loaded by `revtex4-1`. To modify it, add the following lines to your preamble, with suitable values for `BEFORE` and `AFTER`.

```
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchcmd\bibsection{19}{AFTER}{}{}
\xpatchcmd\bibsection{\begingroup}{\vskip BEFOREpt\begingroup}{}{}
```

Some examples:

- `BEFORE=0` and `AFTER=19` yield the normal layout.

  ```
  \xpatchcmd\bibsection{19}{19}{}{}
  \xpatchcmd\bibsection{\begingroup}{\vskip0pt\begingroup}{}{}
  ```

  [image]
- `BEFORE=-10` and `AFTER=9` reduce the space by 10pt on both sides.

  ```
  \xpatchcmd\bibsection{19}{9}{}{}
  \xpatchcmd\bibsection{\begingroup}{\vskip-10pt\begingroup}{}{}
  ```

  [image]
- `BEFORE=-19` and `AFTER=0` remove the space completely.

  ```
  \xpatchcmd\bibsection{19}{0}{}{}
  \xpatchcmd\bibsection{\begingroup}{\vskip-19pt\begingroup}{}{}
  ```

  [image]